# How to use local variable in another function in C++?

Tags: c++

How to use local variable `treasureX` in another function `win`? In the `win` function, the program works using `board[6][t]` but not `treasureX`. The `treasureX` variable is global but code is not working as intended.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

char board[8][8];
char treasureX;
int t;

void Board() {
    for (int x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < 7; y++) {
            board[x][y] = '.';
        }
    }
}


void treasureSpawn() {
    t = rand() % 6 + 1;
    board[6][t] = 'X';
    treasureX = board[6][t];
}

int displayBoard() {
    for (int x = 0; x<8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y<8; y++) {
            std::cout << board[x][y];
            if (y == 7) {
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char playerPosition;

char playerSpawn() {
    int randomY;
    randomY = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    board[1][randomY] = 'G';
    playerPosition = board[1][randomY];
    return playerPosition;
}

int movement() {
    char move;
    std::cout << "Use WASD keys to move." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> move;
    for (int x = 1; x<7; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y<8; y++) {
            if (board[x][y] == 'G') {
                board[x][y] = '.';
                if (move == 'W' || move == 'w') {
                    return board[x - 1][y] = 'G';
                }
                else if (move == 'A' || move == 'a') {
                    return board[x][y - 1] = 'G';
                }
                else if (move == 'D' || move == 'd') {
                    return board[x][y + 1] = 'G';
                }
                else if (move == 'S' || move == 's') {
                    return board[x + 1][y] = 'G';
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Wrong key!" << std::endl;
                    movement();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int win() {
    if (treasureX == 'G') { // when player arrives at 'X' this function does not execute. Works if I put 'board[6][t]' instead of 'treasureX'.
        std::cout << "You win" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    Board();
    playerSpawn();
    outOfBounds();
    treasureSpawn();
    displayBoard();
    do {
        movement();
        checkIf();
        displayBoard();
    } while (win() != 0);
}
```

Comment: `treasureX` is not a local variable. It is a global variable.

Comment: don't use global variables. You can have it in one class and access it using a getter from anywhere else you would like.

Comment: spare me, it has been long since i've used c++ and I am trying to jog my memory.

Comment: You probably also want to store the *treasure's location* not the *letter X*, and similarly the *player's location* and not the *letter G*. Something like a  `std::pair<int, int>` or a `struct Position { int x; int y; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition of treasureX to be `const char & treasureX = treasureSpawn();` and treasureSpawn to be

```
const char & treasureSpawn() {
    t = rand() % 6 + 1;
    board[6][t] = 'X';
    return board[6][t];
}
```

then the value of treasureX will change when the player moves over it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I need to revise, I forgot all about pointers, stacks, classes, structs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `TreasureX` is a variable inintialized in function `void treasureSpawn()`, and its value is not changed throughout the program (And always be `'X'`).
However, `board[6][t]` is changed while the program is executing, more precisely in the `int movement()` function, hence their values are different when the program executed the function `win()`